# How to configure own server address in RocketChat Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, rocket.chat

I have download and build the RocketChat cordova android application Sucessfully,
but by default it points to the demo server i.e "https://demo.rocket.chat"

I have created my own server for the chat application .

How do i configure my own server in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Swipe two fingers up the mobile screen, and you will get a list of server, so you can add the URL for your own.